# iOS: Adding row to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that is based on a array of DB results, these results contains a date field. I have a custom cell that contains an image and labels. I'm trying to do:

At cellForRowAtIndexPath I verify if the date of current item (objectAtIndex:indexPath.row) has date field bigger than the last item (objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1). If this is true: I want to add a cell filling the ImageView with a certain image, but I need to add a new row just for show this image.

How can I do this? I'm already doing this verification, but I need to add a new cell...

Comment: Are you sure you need an extra row? Can't you just use 2 different types of cells - one has the big image and another does not have the big image?

Comment: yes, but I need to display two cells...So, I need a extra row

Comment: If you want better answers, you should probably elaborate on your question more. It's not apparent why you need 1 row for some data objects and 2 for others. Also, how are you sorting these objects? Why does their order matter? How does the order of the objects change? Can the user reorder them? What is significant about a date being greater than the immediately preceding date?

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to decide how many cells you want to have. At the point this method is called you should have already setup the data source to provide table view with all information needed.

Here is what you need to do. Refactor your code in a way so you:

1. Setup the data source first.
2. Force reload of the table view either by calling the `reloadData` method.

Answer (score 1):

hey you can add the object in your data base(for example ns array) and refresh the table view with method

> [tableView reloadData];

then the method cell for row at index path will be called again and it will refresh the table view's items.just make sure the method cellforrawantindexpath in your code knows to handle the new data type(make validations).

Answer (score 1):

Your tableView data source should not contain any of that logic where the content of once cell depends on the content of another cell. Instead, you should have a data item for each requested indexPath and that data item should contain ALL logic necessary for the cell to be configured. If an action on that cell has an effect on how another cell should look, you apply a change to the corresponding data-item, and then call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: for the indexPaths.

In short: configure cells ONLY in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:willDisplayCellAtIndexPath, and ONLY do configuring. Other logic should be placed in some data(-controller) object.

As suggested, you should add an item to your data-array. Then call -insertRowAtIndexPath: on the tableView. ReloadData is like a big ugly hammer that you only use when ALL of the data for that tableView changes.